# Spell-check doesn't work on words with dashes (Mail.app in Yosemite)

Tags: macos, mail.app, spellcheck

I just upgraded to Yosemite, and noticed that in Mail.app spell check (as you type) doesn't work properly if two words are connected by a dash (hyphen) and only the second one is misspelled. For example:

1. test-test (no squiggly)
2. test-asdf (no squiggly)
3. asdf-test (squiggly on first word)
4. asdf-asdf (squiggly on first word)

Here #2 should get a squiggly but it does not. All other applications seem to work as expected (although I'd prefer to have squigglies on both words for #4). I have Mac OS 10.10.2 and Mail.app 8.2 (2070.6).

Any suggestions for workarounds?

Comment: What is your setting for spelling? automatic by Language ? or by specific language ?

Comment: Nothing to do with dashes, it already shows the "asdf" as problem without a dash.

Comment: US English. The problem is #2, e.g. if you type in "Merriam-Webter" instead of "Merriam-Webster" you want Mail.app to give you a squiggly.

Comment: You are right, it use the dash to make it one word and ignores the word after dash. But if the word before dash is wrong Webter-Merriam it will show both as incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a answer...but to show the result of a test

It confirms a problem with using a dash with spell checker in Mail.app and Notes ect... on my MBA with 10.9.5

[image: spell check]

The result is sporadic, sometimes if the word before dash is correct it will ignore the word after dash, sometimes not.

Interestingly if I enable check Grammar with Spelling it will work correctly.